# Find Running PHP File in Centos7

Tags: php, linux, centos

I am using a PHP 7.1, I have a problem to find which PHP file is running, it's because when I run this command

```
ps aux | grep php
```

It's returning this output:

```
User   3401  0.0  0.1 317068 14612 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 /usr/bin/php71-cgi
User   3402  0.0  0.4 344416 35564 ?        S    May18   0:00 /usr/bin/php71-cgi
User   3403  0.0  0.4 346596 39420 ?        S    May18   0:00 /usr/bin/php71-cgi
User   3404  0.0  0.4 346596 39432 ?        S    May18   0:00 /usr/bin/php71-cgi
```

I don't know which file is running by this user in the background. is there a way to find which file is running instead of PHP71-CGI?

I am using Centos 7

Comment: try the command: which php

Comment: On command line: try 'top' then 'e' and enter the user name to list processes being run by that user.  It should include the name of the file that way.